# Symmetry of $r = \sin (2 \theta)$ regarding polar axis, pole and line $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: polar-coordinates, curves

When graphing polar plots, one way to make our job easier is to determine if the graphic is symmetric somehow. Regarding polar plots, we have

**Symmetry wrt (with respect to) the polar axis:** When the expression remains unchanged if $r(-\theta) = r(\theta)$

**Symmetry wrt the pole:** When the expression remains unchanged if $-r= r$

**Symmetry wrtto the line $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$:** When the expression remains unchanged if $r(\pi-\theta) = r(\theta)$

That worked fine until I encountered the following example:

$$r=\sin(2\theta)$$

When plotting the graph, we can clearly see that its symmetry "works" for all three conditions listed above.

[image]

But, knowing that

$$r = \sin(2\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$$

the three conditions do not look verified, since

$$r(-\theta) = 2 \sin(-\theta) \cos(-\theta) = - 2 \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\\
-r = - 2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)\\
r(\pi-\theta) = 2 \sin(\pi-\theta) \cos(\pi-\theta) = - 2 \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$$

So my question is: is this graph really symmetrical given the three "conditions"? If so, how can it be explained that algebra isn't in agreement with that fact?

Comment: $r(\pi-\theta)=-r(\theta)$ is clearly another translation of this symmetry.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: You established $r(\pi-\theta)$=-r(\theta)=r(-\theta)$   w.r.t. the vertical  axis (actually, there are 4 axes of symmetry and a central symmetry).